# What's the BNB Contract Address on Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

What is the BNB contract address on **Binance Smart Chain** if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BNB is the native currency of the Binance Smart Chain, just like ETH is the native currency of Ethereum.

So there is no contract address for BNB.

If you really want a BEP20 token matching your BNB you should convert them to Wrapped BNB (WBNB).

You can find more information [here](https://www.binance.org/en/blog/what-is-wbnb/).

Comment: Thx a lot, when I have the BNB in my wallet, is it wBNB?

Comment: No, if its BNB it's BNB not WBNB. If you whish to convert to WBNB the link I gave you shows the procedure to follow with direct interactions with the WBNB contract. BNB has a 1 to 1 ratio with WBNB though so should you convert you will end up with as much WBNB as you had BNB to start with.

Comment: So BNB is not bound to a solidity contract running on BSC?